How do I extract substrings immediately before the nearest punctuation?
From a text file using Python 3.12, how do I extract substrings from lines that have multiple parentheses:
line1: 'group(something)'
line2: 'other(something) and group(something,something,something) and not group(something,something)'

I'm only interested in the 'something' 's from the 'group()' or 'not group()'.
def find_within(search_in, search_for, until):
    return search_in[search_in.find(search_for) + len(search_for) : search_in.find(until)]

group1 = find_within(line1, 'group(', ')')        # extracting group from the first line
group2 = find_within(line2, 'and group(', ')')    # extracting group from the second line
not_group = find_within(line2, 'not group(', ')')    # extracting 'not group' from the second line

This function can handle extraction from lines that have only a single 'group()' like line1 but not the lines with multiple items like line2 (it would return null). I tried replacing the last .find() by .rfind():
def find_within(search_in, search_for, until):
    return search_in[search_in.find(search_for) + len(search_for) : search_in.rfind(until)]

But the output was:

'something,something,something) and not group(something,something'

while I expect:

'something,something,something'

.find() looks for the first occurrence of the parenthesis, so when I'm seeking 'something' from 'group(something)' that is in the middle of the string, .find() looks at the closing parenthesis from a pair ahead of 'group(something)', so returns ''. And .rfind() looks for the last occurrence of the parenthesis so extracts everything until the last parenthesis.
Is there a better way with .find() or do I need regular expressions?

What's inputs and expected outputs? You can use \bgroup\s*\(([^)]+)\)|and\s+group\(([^)]+)\)|and\s+not\s+group\(([^)]+)\)|\bother\(([^)]+)\)

I think the thing that you may be missing is that you can give str.find() a second optional integer argument (str.find(target, offset)) to tell where you want to start the search.
So in the example below we being with start = 0 for start of string
if we find the target string we advance start by offset to point to the character just past the '(' character.  Then we search from that position forward to find the next ')' character which is our stop position
then the contents of the parentheses are just a slice from stop to start.  In my example I then appended the contents to a list but you could print it out, or whatever you needed
eventually str.find() will return -1 indicating there are no further matches so we return from the function
text = "group(a, b, c) and group(d, e, f) and not group(g, h, i)"    


def findit(target, text):
    
    """look for target followed by (
       save the text following the ( until the next )
       append that text to results
       when target doesn't match any more return results"""
       
    results = []
    target += '('    #add open parenthesis after target
    offset = len(target)
    
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = text.find(target, start)
        #print(start)
        if start == -1:
            break
        
        start += offset
        stop = text.find(')', start)
        contents = text[start:stop]
        results.append(contents)
        
    return results

print("\ngroup")
print(findit('group', text))

print("\nand group")
print(findit('and group', text))

print("\nnot group")
print(findit('not group', text))

this program will produce this output:
group
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g, h, i']

and group
['d, e, f']

not group
['g, h, i']


Thank you @quizdog! Your approach helped me to figure out the 'offset' parameter I was missing. I ended up using the following function and it worked finally :)
"""
def find_within(search_in, target, stop_before):             start = search_in.find(target) + len(target)             stop = search_in.find(stop_before, start)             return search_in[start : stop]
"""

Glad to help! To be honest I first thought about writing a regular expression as well but you saw from some of the other answers how complicated that can get!

You can use a pattern to find the expected outputs:
\b(group)\s*\(([^)]+)\)|\s*(\band\s+group)\(([^)]+)\)|\s*(\band\s+not\s+group)\(([^)]+)\)|\s*\b(other)\(([^)]+)\)

Code:
import re


def _find(p, s):
    return re.findall(p, s)


p = r'\b(group)\s*\(([^)]+)\)|\s*(\band\s+group)\(([^)]+)\)|\s*(\band\s+not\s+group)\(([^)]+)\)|\s*\b(other)\(([^)]+)\)'
s = """
line1: 'group(something)'
line2: 'other(something) and group(something,something,something) and not group(something,something)'
I'
"""
print(_find(p, s))



Prints
[('group', 'something', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '', 'other', 'something'), ('', '', 'and group', 'something,something,something', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', 'and not group', 'something,something', '', '')]



Notes

There are 8 capture groups: four groups are the keys and four groups  are the values.
\(([^)]+)\): These four groups are the values.


Edit
You can use a simple pattern and get all the keys and values, and then  proceed with your text processing tasks:
import re


def _find(p, s, as_dict=False):
    matches = re.findall(p, s)
    if as_dict:
        return {m[0].strip(): m[1] for m in matches}
    return matches


p = r"\s*([^(']+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)"
s = """
line1: 'group(something)'
line2: 'other(something) and group(something,something,something) and not group(something,something)'
I'
"""

print(_find(p, s))

print(_find(p, s, as_dict=True))


Prints
[('group', 'something'), ('other', 'something'), ('and group', 'something,something,something'), ('and not group', 'something,something')]
{'group': 'something', 'other': 'something', 'and group': 'something,something,something', 'and not group': 'something,something'}


Details
The second pattern is pretty simple:

([^(']+): capture group 1 finds the keys.
\s*\(([^)]+)\): capture group 2 finds the values.
[^(']+: means all the chars are allowed, except (i.e., ^) these two [('], and then one or more times (i.e., +).
([^)]+): means all chars are allowed, except (i.e., ^) one char, that is the one, ), in the character class (i.e., []).


Solution in TXR Lisp:
Given the file data containing:
group(alpha)
other(something) and group(beta,gamma,delta) and not group(phi,epsilon)
foo(else) and not group(zeta)

we run:
$ txr group.tl < data
:left -> alpha
:and-not -> phi epsilon zeta
:and -> beta gamma delta

Where group.tl is:
(defun term (oper expr)
  (if-match `@oper(@args)` expr
    (spl "," args)))

(defun expr (oper line)
  (match-case line
    (`and not @expr @more`
      ^((:and-not ,*(term oper expr)) ,*(expr oper more)))
    (`and not @expr`
      ^((:and-not ,*(term oper expr))))
    (`and @expr @more`
      ^((:and ,*(term oper expr)) ,*(expr oper more)))
    (`and @expr`
      ^((:and ,*(term oper expr))))
    (`@expr @more`
      ^((:left ,*(term oper expr)) ,*(expr oper more)))
    (@else
      ^((:left ,*(term oper else))))))

(flow (get-lines)
  (mappend (op expr "group"))
  (group-map first (op mappend rest))
  (dohash (k v @1)
    (put-line `@k -> @v`)))

It's a simple pattern matching on the phrase structure of the expressions, whose output is keyword-tagged lists of strings like (:left "alpha" "beta").
We catenate these together from multiple lines of the file, tabulate them into a hash table, then print.
